# Ising model operators

Tags: condensed-matter, operators, conformal-field-theory, ising-model, lattice-model

Ising model formulated as lattice theory with local degrees of freedom described by $s_i$ $i\in 1, \dots, N$ and energy:
$$
E[\sigma_i] = -J\sum_{<ij>} s_i s_j
$$

From $s_i$ I can construct a lot of different operators and calculate correlation functions in large volume limit.

**1) How can I found operators which will have fixed scaling dimension?**

**2) How many of such operators are exist?**

I wanna to understand this questions from **microscopic description** of Ising system. But in [EPFL Lectures on Conformal Field Theory in D>= 3 Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000) I have read:

[image]

Is some way to answer this question from microscopic description?